# Can this code be shorter and easier to implement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

Im making one script for node red and i want to make it simple to implement. How can i compress this code even more?

```
var notDetected = "NOT DETECTED";
var models = [
    context.get('model1')||notDetected,
    context.get('model2')||notDetected,
    context.get('model3')||notDetected,
    context.get('model4')||notDetected
];
switch(msg.topic)
{
    case "core_1":
        models[0] = msg.model + "";
        context.set('model1', models[0]);
        break;
    case "core_2":
        models[1] = msg.model + "";
        context.set('model2', models[1]);
        break;
    case "core_3":
        models[2] = msg.model + "";
        context.set('model3', models[2]);
        break;
    case "core_4":
        models[3] = msg.model + "";
        context.set('model4', models[3]);
        break;
}
var msgs = [
    {payload: models[0]},
    {payload: models[1]},
    {payload: models[2]},
    {payload: models[3]}
];
return msgs;
```

Can models be compressed even more? What about msgs? Can i remove that id inside for models to match msgs id, for example

```
msg[x] = {payload: models[x]};
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Since this question is not about programming problem, I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is much better place to ask it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that one. Learned something again.

Comment: @phi1010 I also found it in some comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compressing the code in terms of readability/extensibility (not necessarily space):

- You can use a loop to fill the `models` and `msgs` array,
- You can split the `core_X` string at the first "_" to get the index, but this might cause security issues if you don't validate the input; or you can use a map from the four strings `core_1` to the actual number.

Take a look here for the for loop: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

It could look like this:

```
var msgs = [];
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
    msgs[x] = {payload: models[x]};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i found another way to fix my problem but i will use this in future. Thanks a lot! Its 2:30am here, i cant think right..

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap context.get() in a single function and re-use it in your *models* array, so that you won't have to change every single index in the array when you make a change to that.

Example:

```
var notDetected = "NOT DETECTED";

var getContext = function(str) {
  return context.get(str) || "NOT DETECTED";
}

var models = [
    getContext('model1'),
    getContext('model2'),
    getContext('model3'),
    getContext('model4'),
];
```

If you need to make a change to context.get() you can just change it once in the function like so: `differentContext.get(str) || "NOT DETECTED"`

Without that you woud have to change every index:

```
var models = [
    differentContext.get('model1')||notDetected,
    differentContext.get('model2')||notDetected,
    differentContext.get('model3')||notDetected,
    differentContext.get('model4')||notDetected
];
```

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking a little i made a script that will just redirect 4 messages to where they need to go and then use needed parameters in another script or just get msg.model from whole msg. Here is splitter code:

```
var notDetected = {};
var msgs = [
    context.get('msg1')||notDetected,
    context.get('msg2')||notDetected,
    context.get('msg3')||notDetected,
    context.get('msg4')||notDetected
];
switch(msg.topic)
{
    case "core_1":
        context.set('msg1', msg);
        break;
    case "core_2":
        context.set('msg2', msg);
        break;
    case "core_3":
        context.set('msg3', msg);
        break;
    case "core_4":
        context.set('msg4', msg);
        break;
}
return msgs;
```

And in text node i just set to use msg.model value. Now i just got splitter that is more useful.